# Typescript and exported function syntax

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was reading ngx-translate documentation and I found this pieces of code (that are explaining the correct way to make the project Aot compatible.

**First**

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],...
```

**Second**

```
// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],...
```

My question is: what is the difference between enclosing the function name passed for `useFactory` with parenthesis and passing it plain?

Thanks

Comment: there is no difference between those methods. Both are AOT compatible

Comment: but what is the difference between:
useFactory: functionName 
and 
useFactory: (functionName)
?? Thanks!

Comment: the difference is parenthesis. Or what else should I say? THERE. IS. NO. DIFFERENCE.

Comment: read the answer below and you understand my question .

Comment: this answer does not answer your question. It does not tell what is the difference between parenthesis and none. My removed answer was totally the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are being slightly mis-led by a quirk in the examples in the documentation.

The non-AOT version *could* be:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (http: HttpClient) {
                    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
                },
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],...
```

And the AOT version must have an exported function...

```
export function yourFunction(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: yourFunction,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],...
```

In other words:

> If you want to configure a custom TranslateLoader while using AoT compilation or Ionic, you must use an exported function instead of an inline function.